# java multiple constructors

Tags: java, constructor, code-duplication

If I have multiple constructors in a class, how do I avoid duplicate code for those fields which are initialized identically for all constructors, or is this not preferable?

For example:

```
class ComparableThing<K extends Comparable<K>> {
  private int someField;
  private Comparator<K> comparator;

  public ComparableThing() {
    this.someField = 0;
    this.comparator = Comparator.naturalOrder();
  }

  public ComparableThing(Comparator<K> comp) {
    this.someField = 0;
    this.comparator = comp;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the duplicate code in initializing `someField`, or is this duplicate code considered acceptable/preferable?

Answer (score 1):

You can chain the constructors.  Call a more general constructor from a more specific constructor.  It's not uncommon.

```
class ComparableThing<K extends Comparable<K>> {
  private int someField;
  private Comparator<K> comparator;

  public ComparableThing(Comparator<K> comp) {  // more general constructor
    this.someField = 0;
    this.comparator = comp;
  }

  public ComparableThing() {
    this(Comparator.naturalOrder());
  }
}
```